# Override belongs_to has_many foreign key value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have something set-up with two models.  `user` and `posts`.  user `has_many` posts and posts `belongs_to` user.  I created a bunch of posts using one admin `user` and now I want to assign each post to a different `user`.  I tried creating a `form` for `post` and just updating the `user_id` field, but I get the message `Unpermitted parameter: user_id` and the field will not update - it just reverts back to the original `user_id`.

How can I force the form to accept the new `user_id`?

Answer (score 1):

Just had to add `:user_id` to params in the controller.  Foolish oversight.